# Connecting to NAS server on different subnet at home

Tags: router, nas, subnet, asuswrt-merlin

Attached you will find diagram of my home network + tracert. Please review before reading below, to help with context.

I have two routers. One has my NAS server and regular  daily traffic. The second router is setup with NordVPN with killswitch. The second router has all traffic going through VPN.

Computer 1 is able to mount NAS server.

Computer 2 is able to ping the NAS server and I am able to access it using the IP address in Chrome. It takes me to the server GUI. However, I am unable to mount the drive to computer 2 in file explorer - it can't find the server.

What have I tried?

1. Make sure its setup as a private network
2. Make sure file sharing is turned on computer 2
3. Tried turning off firewall at computer 2, router 1, and router 2
4. Computer 2 is able to mount the NAS server if I am connected to router 1, but it does not mount when connected to router 2.

[image: Network layout + Tracert]

Comment: If you can ping NAS from PC2, but can't mount file-share its likely router2-asus or even tp-link-router1 has a firewall blocking SMB/file-share network ports. 1)which port on router1 connects to router2? I suspect LAN. 2)cable from router1 to router2, which port is it connected to on router2, WAN/Internet? 3)VPN on router2 may also be complicating things. Can you temporarily turn it off to understand if that is culprit or factor?

Comment: Naming can be an issue when you are using split tunneling with a VPN. are you trying to connect to SMB by name or by IP or both?

Comment: Please do the steps in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1810603/why-cant-i-reach-my-raspberry-pi-with-the-hostname-i-set-for-it/1810693#1810693) answer, ensuring Router 2 is set to the same _local domain_ as Router 1

Answer (score -1):

If your LAN diagram is true to form there's an easy solution, but this WILL degrade security.
On router 1 - put the NAS server in the DMZ for all incoming connections.
You should then be able to access the NAS from PC2 by using the IP address of the router 192.168.0.1 to access the NAS.
If router 1 is connected to the internet this WILL give the internet access to the NAS; not a good answer but very workable.

---

This could also work - use a USB SSD/HDD plugged into the Router 1 & get router 1 to share access to this, ie use the router as your NAS....
Another solution: VPN's can run in two modes - Client to LAN, or client to single device - Serve the VPN at the NAS. On my router (Asus N66U) allowing access to the LAN was a simple tick-box in the config page. But to access the NAS on my PC from the internet I had to use the NAS IP address, not it's WINs name.
Finally - apparently your router supports  "virtual server", which could allow you to forward the NAS as a server towards the VPN connection, but for this you'll have to read the manual. This is a possibility.

Comment: An NAS should never be put in a DMZ - an NAS is **_always_** meant to run behind a router's stateful firewall

Comment: I said the same in my answer; personally I think the fault is that he forgot to tick the box allowing LAN access on the VPN configuration.