# Why can't I reach my raspberry pi with the hostname I set for it?

Tags: linux, networking, dns

I have two computers on my home network: a Raspberry Pi 4 and a Windows laptop. My Raspberry Pi is running the default Raspbian that it comes with. I'm trying to set a hostname for my Raspberry Pi so that it can be accessed on the network with that hostname.

The Raspberry Pi is at `192.168.0.40`, and the Windows laptop is at `192.168.0.140`.

I changed the `/etc/hostname` file from `raspberrypi` to `phobos`, which is the hostname I want to use.

`/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this:

```
  1 # Generated by resolvconf
  2 domain cable.rcn.com
  3 nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

`/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` looks like this:

```
  1 # Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient.
  2 #
  3 # This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
  4 #       man page for more information about the syntax of this file
  5 #       and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
  6 #       dhclient.
  7 #
  8 # Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
  9 #       not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
 10 #       few changes must be made to this file, if any.
 11 #
 12
 13 option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
 14
 15 send host-name = gethostname();
 16 request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
 17         domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
 18         dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
 19         netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
 20         rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
```

The `hostname` command returns `phobos`.

When I attempt to ping the Raspberry Pi from my Windows laptop, I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Leo> ping phobos
Ping request could not find host phobos. Please check the name and try again.
```

However, when I ping for `raspberrypi`, which was the original hostname I found in the `/etc/hostname` file, I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Leo> ping raspberrypi

Pinging raspberrypi.cable.rcn.com [192.168.0.40] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.40: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.40: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.40: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.40: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.40:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 4ms, Maximum = 6ms, Average = 5ms
```

This makes me think that my router (an Arris DG3450A) is not updating the hostname for the Raspberry Pi in its DHCP settings, but I'm not sure how to notify it to do so. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Please let me know if there's any other information I could provide.

Comment: Router has no idea how to route the traffic without the following: **(1) _Router_:** Local Doman name _must_ be the same across all devices, and all clients must match what is set as the Local Domain on the router _(often `.local` or `.lan`, but it can be customized to anything - e.g. I use `wrt` since I use OpenWrt on my router)_; **(2) _Raspberry Pi_:** Local domain set to Router's Local Domain; **(3) _Windows_:** Local Domain set to Router's Local Domain _(uses the Workgroup name as the Local Domain)_; **(4) _Windows_:** hostname entry for Raspberry Pi in the `%WinDir%\System32\etc\hosts`

Comment: If you have another RPi, you could use it as a DNS server, maybe with something like [Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/). You would need to set the DHCP to give out the address of the DNS server. Then you can set the DNS entries in just one place instead of on every device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access devices by `hostname`, the router and client devices must all be correctly configured to do so, else a router has no idea how to route the traffic.

When accessing devices by hostname, they're accessed on the router's end via `<hostname>.<LocalDomain>`, which isn't configured via DHCP, so the following must be done:

1. ***Router*:**

   1. **Static IP set for devices being accessed via `hostname`:**

      ```cpp
      IP      '192.168.0.40'
      mac     'A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6'
      name    'Phobos'
      ```
   2. ***Local Doman* name on Router *must* be the same across all devices**

      - Default *Local Domain* is often `.local` or `.lan`, but can be customized to anything
      - All clients must match what is set as the *Local Domain* on the router
2. ***Windows*:**

   1. ***Local Domain* is the Workgroup name, and it's set via:**

      - **GUI:** 
         <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* `SystemPropertiesAdvanced` → OK

        1. Tab: *Computer Name* → *Change...* → *Member of*
        2. *Workgroup:* `<LocalDomain>` → OK → OK
      - **CLI:** 
         <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* `powershell` → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+OK

        1. Either [`Add-Computer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-computer?view=powershell-5.1) or [`wmic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem) can be used:

           ```powershell
           # PowerShell:
             Add-Computer -WorkGroupName "<LocalDomain>"

           # Windows Management Instrumentation Command:
             wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" call joindomainorworkgroup name="<LocalDomain>"
           ```
   2. **Set client `hostname` entry in `%WinDir%\System32\etc\hosts`:**

      ```powershell
      #

               ##::[[---  Windows Host Config  ---]]::##

      #===========================================================
                          ##----- LAN -----##
      #===========================================================

        # Static IP:        Hostname:     Hostname.LocalDomain:
          192.168.0.1       <router>      <router>.lan
          192.168.0.40      Phobos        Phobos.lan
      ```
   3. **Reboot**
3. ***Raspberry Pi*:** 
    **Set to Router's Local Domain** *(varies by distro)* → **Reboot**

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. One thing I'm not quite understanding, though, is why I can reach my raspberry pi from my Windows machine via the `raspberrypi` hostname. If a hostname needs to be manually set in the router and in the Windows machine in order to work, how did the `raspberrypi` hostname get configured automatically without me doing anything?

Comment: @Leo technically a static IP doesn't need to be set on the router, but I always put it as a recommended step since it guarantees there will never be an issue when accessing devices via hostname, regardless of OS or client device.

Answer (score 0):

Hostname resolution on IP networks has always been a trickier and less intuitive topic than anyone new might expect.

Setting your own host's name local to that host doesn't mean anything to anyone else on the network. You can't expect that name change to get automatically advertised on the network or automatically registered with any name server via any of the plethora of service discovery and name resolution protocols that have been used over time. So you have to decide for yourself which ways you want your host's name to be discoverable and resolvable by other devices over the network, and find ways to make that happen.

If your Raspberry Pi is running an implementation of multicast DNS (mDNS) such as Avahi, then if the Avahi daemon knows to look up your hostname in `/etc/hostname` for via the `hostname(1)` command, your device should show up on your network as *hostname.local* (e.g. phobos.local).

If you're not using mDNS on your network, you may need to manually update your local DNS server to have an entry for phobos.example.com (don't use .local; leave .local for ZeroConf/mDNS).

DHCP is about clients requesting configuration settings from servers, not about clients pushing information like hostnames to the server. And it's never used for hostname to IP address resolution. The DHCP protocol does provide a way for DHCP clients to inform the DHCP server what the client considers its own hostname to be, but it's mostly informative, and most DHCP servers don't contain a mechanism to push that client-defined hostname over to any nearby DNS servers, or advertise it via any other service discovery or name resolution protocols. But it's possible that your home gateway device (your Arris DG3450A) does have some sort of integration between its embedded DHCP server and its embedded DNS service.

When it comes to client devices registering their own self-defined hostnames to DNS servers, there are solutions based on proper standards-track protocols like DNS UPDATE (RFC 2136), and also less standard, but perhaps more widespread, de facto market solutions like Dynamic DNS (DDNS).

I don't think you said what you're using as your DNS server, but you might want to see if it supports DNS UPDATE or DDNS, and see if your Raspbian environment has a client for either of those protocols.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned- my router is acting as my DNS server. Your description of DHCP makes sense, but then what did my raspberry pi use to notify my router of its original `raspberrypi` hostname? That hostname does work from other devices on the network and I didn't configure anything- it just worked out of the box when I put the raspberry pi on the network.

Comment: @Leo I'm guessing your router is a rare one that features a proprietary integration between its embedded DHCP server and its embedded DNS server, so the hostname your RPi mentions in its DHCP Request gets plugged into the DNS server process's table of hostname to IP address mappings for you LAN devices.

Answer (score 0):

There is one manually operated way to get local IP's replaced by hostnames...

On every local machine, edit your `/etc/hosts`-file
*(alt. `C:\Windows\System32\etc\hosts` if I remember correctly)*.

Add a line stating e.g.
`129.168.0.40 pi4 raspberry4 rp4 hobby play`

and you will be able to use any of those names in place of the IP.

Notable caveat; if you change the IP, you need to manually change it in every active instance of the file.
i.e. keep it on a single "server" (with a running sshd) and `scp` it onto other machines?

*(There are means to run a script at [Shell] startup, out of the scope here)*
*Linux Hint: [sudo for just one command IN lost+found folder, not more](https://superuser.com/q/1809789/346288)*

*Idea: Create a script that runs on every local computer, and `scp`'s /etc/hostname to the sshd-server, which then can append all those together and provide as local hosts file.*